# Integrating scalar field over $p$-norm balls and/or their surface

Tags: integration, metric-spaces, surface-integrals

Suppose we're working in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For $1\leq p<\infty$ we define the $p$-norm $||\cdot||_p$ as $||(x,y,z)||_p$.

Now, let $f$ be a scalar field in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I want to compute the volume integral of the field over the ball and/or the surface integral over the border of the ball. Is there a parametrization of the surface of the ball? Or some coordinates in which I can compute the volume integral?

Of course, the case $p=2$ is clear and easy, as one may use spherical coordinates, and the case $p=\infty$ is even easier, as the ball is simply a cube. But what about doing it for a general $p$? Is it even possible? I feel like this should be reasonably easy to compute but I don't really know what to do.

Comment: There is obviously a parametrisation of of the $p$-norm sphere by "expand points of usual $S^2$ radially out by factor $\lVert x\rVert_p/\lVert x\rVert_2$", and similarly for the (punctured) ball.  It is not going to be nice ($p=1,2,\infty$ are probably the only nice cases).

Comment: I believe what we actually ought to do is to expand by a factor $||x||_2/||x||_p$, but yeah, the idea works, thank you!